# Save .xlsx files in a folder to .csv files

Tags: excel, vba

I tried this script to convert xlsx files to csv.

I want the old files to be in the folder and the name on csv file to be exact as xlsx file.

I am getting `.` extra on the csv extension like `filename..csv`.

```
Sub ConvertCSVToXlsx()

    Dim myfile As String
    Dim oldfname As String, newfname As String
    Dim workfile
    Dim folderName As String

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'   Capture name of current file
    myfile = ActiveWorkbook.Name

'   Set folder name to work through
    folderName = "C:\Test\"

'   Loop through all CSV filres in folder
    workfile = Dir(folderName & "*.xlsx")
    Do While workfile <> ""
'       Open CSV file
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=folderName & workfile
'       Capture name of old CSV file
        oldfname = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
'       Convert to XLSX
        newfname = folderName & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 4) & ".CSV"
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=newfname, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
'       Delete old CSV file
        Kill oldfname
        Windows(myfile).Activate
        workfile = Dir()
    Loop

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 4)  should be Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 5)

Comment: There is a lot going on here, and it is really too much for a general purpose question. The question can be improved by stripping the code down to the bare minimum which shows the problem. However, thank you for contributing to StackOverflow for the first time. I will give +1 for first post. Consider how you can simplify to the minimum code to address the issue.

Comment: @M.K.Hunter-what part of the code is too much for you, and what do you suggest in regards to trimming it down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty close.
Your comments are a bit confusing in the code.

If you are going to use left(len()-4 then you need to change the part to add csv without the period.
newfname = oldfname & "CSV"

Just a bit of an edit with the saveas line

You don't kill the original workbook, that deletes it from the folder.

The original workbook is no longer opened because you saved it as a new filename.

```
Sub ConvertCSVToXlsx()

    Dim myfile As String
    Dim oldfname As String, newfname As String
    Dim workfile
    Dim folderName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '   Capture name of current file
    myfile = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    '   Set folder name to work through
    folderName = "C:\New folder\"

    '   Loop through all CSV filres in folder
    workfile = Dir(folderName & "*.xlsx")
    Do While workfile <> ""
        '       Open CSV file
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=folderName & workfile
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        '       Capture name of old CSV file
        oldfname = Left(wb.FullName, Len(wb.FullName) - 4)
        '       Convert to XLSX
        newfname = oldfname & "CSV"
        wb.SaveAs Filename:=newfname, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        wb.Close
        workfile = Dir()
    Loop

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It is working fine, but for credit card numbers it is going to scientific annotation. Is there a way to work around this please??

Comment: Thanks halfer and Davesexcel for your valuable inputs

Comment: It would be best to import the csv file into excel, not try and open it from windows explorer. Goto Data tab and select "Get External data" then "From Text". Do a webSearch , "Import CSV files into excel"